# symfony 3 render controller in twig

Tags: symfony, controller, twig, render

in twig template

```
{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:SecurityController:login',{})) }}
```

THE ERROR :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   _controller value "FOSUserBundle:SecurityController:login" maps to a "FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityControllerController" class, but
>   this class was not found. Create this class or check the spelling of
>   the class and its namespace.")

how declare use namespace in twig template ? Thanks

Comment: have you installed fos user bundle correctly ?

Comment: yes that's work perfectly if i call "....../login" in url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove 'controller' from the render, like this :

`{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login',{})) }}`

Comment: thanks a lot it's like not put Action in the controller function !

Comment: accept my answer (the check sign under the vote part)